# How to see the normal tooltip information in Visual Studio instead of the error help

Tags: visual-studio

If there's an error in my code and I hover over a piece then the tooltip tells me the error, how do I get it to display the normal data (eg class type) instead?

Here's an example of it overriding the tooltip (incase my explanation is fuzzy)

http://www.tarkey.co.uk/cc.PNG

[Image Here](http://www.tarkey.co.uk/cc.PNG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, IntelliSense, Quick Info (on my machine, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I). For parameters, it's Parameter Info (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+P).

Answer (score -1):

By fixing the error.

Comment: Knowing what abstract base type derivative needs to be created is a lot easier when you know the type.